# How to create new cell from keyword of another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate, regexextract

I have a column that has job listings with extra info, so I only want to grab the job position and place it into a new cell.

A1: `Seeking Assistant to the marketing division...`

B1: `Assistant`

(keyword list): Analyst, Assistant, Associate, Coordinator... etc.

Is there a formula or script that creates B1 based on a keyword found in A1 while checking the keyword list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(PROPER(A1:A), 
 "Analyst|Assistant|Associate|Coordinator")))
```

[image: 0]

---

or load them from a column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(PROPER(A1:A), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, E2:E))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That worked great thanks so much!